# jquery dynamic dropdown menu - appending issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a dynamic drop down using JSON info.  Basically it works, but I can't append the sub menu with the parent.  Can anyone give a good suggestion?

json:

```
 "navigation":[
      {
         "title":"Home",
         "link":"index.html"
      },
      {
         "title":"Products",
         "link":"product.html",
         "subnav":[
            {
               "title":"Webapps",
               "link":"products/webapps.html"
            },
            {
               "title":"Mobile Apps",
               "link":"products/mobile-apps.html"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
```

my function :

```
var naviHandler = function (navi) {
    var localNaviData = navi, ul = '<ul>',naviLink="";
    $.map(localNaviData, function (val,i) {
        naviLink +='<li>'
        if(val.subnav){
            naviLink += naviHandler(val.subnav)
        }else{
            naviLink +='<a href='+val.link+'>'+val.title+'</a>'
        }

    })

    naviLink +='</li></ul>';
    $('header').find('nav').append(naviLink);
    }

naviHandler(localData[obj]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create jQuery objects instead of making raw HTML code with jQuery:

```
var create_menu = function(navi) {
    var $ul = $('<ul />');

    $.map(navi, function(val, i) {
        var $li = $('<li />');

        if (val.subnav) {
            create_menu(val.subnav).appendTo($li);
        } else {
            $('<a />', {'href': val.link}).text(val.title).appendTo($li);
        }

        $li.appendTo($ul);
    });

    return $ul;
}

$('header nav').append(create_menu(localData[obj]));
```

Your problem was that the function wasn't `return`ing anything, so using it recursively won't work.

Comment: You are correct, instead of appending to second link (Products), the sub link replacing the link...